# Why does Chrome suddenly stop autocompleting a URL for me?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, autocomplete

Chrome used to complete `cal` to `calendar.google.com` for me, but it stopped working. At the moment I'm on  27.0.1448.0 dev on OS X, but this issue is just affecting my profile, not others, so it's not related to the version, really.

Here's what `chrome://omnibox` says about `cal`:

```
Provider        Type                    Relevance   Contents    URL
Search          search-what-you-typed   1300        cal         https://www.google.at/search?q=cal&oq=cal&aqs=chrome.0.57j65j60l2j0l2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
HistoryQuick    history-url             657         https://www.google.com/calendar/    https://www.google.com/calendar/
HistoryQuick    history-url             656         https://www.google.com/calendar/render  https://www.google.com/calendar/render
```

Here's what I've already tried:

- Removed my entire profile's history from Chrome's personal data settings
- Removed the `Default` folder from Chrome and let it sync anew
- Went to Google.com and removed the past search for "cal" from the web activity

I've tried creating a new profile, typing `calendar.google.com` once, and it works. However, my default profile seems to be messed up in that regard. Any way I can remove the `search-what-you-typed` entry there?

Here's [the whole output](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qKidZSiX) with all providers and all details listed.

Comment: The `search-what-you-typed` entry is the fallback action and it's supposed to be there. The strange thing is that visiting `calendar.google.com` should generate a `HistoryURL` entry with higher relevance, but it doesn't. To troubleshoot, try disable syncing of *Omnibox History*.

Comment: Indeed, I checked with another profile where `HistoryURL history-url 1413 calendar.google.com http://calendar.google.com/` is added. I'm already considering just wiping that profile altogether and starting a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since doing the same in a new profile would work as expected, it seemed there was no other option than to clear the profile. This would mean losing all my history – but I had cleared that anyway before.

I decided to first [remove all of my synced data](https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync). Then, I exported my bookmarks from the Bookmarks Manager (⌥⌘B). Finally, I removed the `Default` folder in my Chrome's application files (`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`) and started Chrome again.

It might be possible to migrate extensions from the `Default`'s `Extensions` folder, but I've decided to re-install the four I had.

If anybody had the same issue and found another way to resolve it, I'd be glad to read about that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that `search-what-you-typed` and `URL-what-you-typed` slowly gain relevance as you use them for other things. You should delete just the `Network Action Predictor` and `Network Action Predictor-journal` files in `%AppData%/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/` or the equivalent on your OS. The `search-what-you-typed` and `URL-what-you-typed` will immediately drop in relevance after a restart, and you're able to keep all your data, including all history.