# Chrome doesn't autocomplete URL to sites in history

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, history, autocomplete

A month ago I was looking at this site:

[image: the picture].

I remember I was looking for one husqarna product. Now when I type `husq` in the URL, it doesn't autocomplete anything and just tries to search it. Is there a way to do it so it shows already visited sites where "husq" was in the link? I think this was working in the past.

There is already a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/570726/why-does-chrome-suddenly-stop-autocompleting-a-url-for-me) about it but answer doesn't work for me since I need NOT to delete history and such.

WIN 10. Chrome v. 61.0.3163.79

Comment: What happens if you try typing the URL?

Comment: @Burgi It only tries to search it. [Like this](https://imgur.com/a/FwV65)

Comment: That isn't the URL though...

Comment: @Burgi Oh well. The same thing sadly happens with URLs too. Typing www.site.co, as well as with http(s) or without it doesn't autocomplete anything and it looks the same as the last picture. Though It works with favourited sites.